# userManager.AddToRoleAsync() - Error: role does not exist

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, asp.net-identity-3

I'm creating a user registration system using .NET Core, Identity Core, and MVC Core. I'm able to create users and create roles in the database.

Here's the form on the view that lets me select a user and select a role to add:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("AddRoleToUser", "Roles"))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

    <p>
        Username : @Html.DropDownList("UserName", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.Users, "Select ...")
        Role Name: @Html.DropDownList("RoleName", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.Roles, "Select ...")

    </p>

    <input type="submit" value="Save" />
}
```

These drop-down lists are populated with users and roles that already exist in the database. They allow me to select `User`s , and the **name** of a role that I've already created. For example, I have a role with the name "admin", this form lets me select the string "admin".

Here's the action that handles adding a role to a user:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<IActionResult> AddRoleToUser(string UserName, string RoleName)
    {
        try
        {
            ApplicationUser user = _db.Users.Where(u => u.UserName.Equals(UserName, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)).FirstOrDefault();
            await _userManager.AddToRoleAsync(user, RoleName);
            PrepopulateDropDownMenus();
            ViewBag.ResultMessage = "Role created successfully!";
            return View("Manage", "Roles");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex);
            return View("Manage");
        }
    }
```

The action never adds the role to the user, and the exception reads "Role "ADMIN" does not exist." with no inner exception. I've tried turning the `RoleName` in the action parameters to all-caps, but it still does not find the role. I've also tried using the role ID instead of the name, which was also unsuccessful.

This exact code worked when I built this app using Identity 3.0 with MVC 6. It seems like something has changed in moving over to Identity Core.

Any thoughts?

**Edit**

Here's the code I'm using to populate the drop-down lists in `RolesController` via the Viewbag:

```
    private void PrepopulateDropDownMenus()
    {
        var rolesList = _db.Roles.OrderBy(r => r.Name).ToList().Select(rr => new SelectListItem { Value = rr.Name.ToString(), Text = rr.Name }).ToList();
        var usersList = _db.Users.OrderBy(u => u.UserName).ToList().Select(uu => new SelectListItem { Value = uu.UserName.ToString(), Text = uu.UserName }).ToList();
        ViewBag.Roles = rolesList;
        ViewBag.Users = usersList;
    }
```

Here's how I add Identity in *Startup.cs* in the `ConfigureServices` method:

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        ...
        services.AddEntityFramework()
            .AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
                options.UseSqlServer(Configuration["ConnectionStrings:DefaultConnection"]));
        services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>()
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
            .AddDefaultTokenProviders();
    }
```

Here's the route in *RolesController.cs* I use to create a new role in the database:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult Create(string rolename)
    {
            _db.Roles.Add(new IdentityRole()
            {
                Name = rolename
            });
            _db.SaveChanges();
            ViewBag.ResultMessage = "Role created successfully!";
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
```

Answer (score 30, accepted):

I can't post comments yet to ask you, so, does your error say **user** admin does not exist, or **role** does not exist?  I tried to duplicate your code on my end, and if the user doesn't exist you'll get a "user can't be null" error.  However, if the role doesn't exist, you'll get a "Role [role] does not exist" error.

I assume that you already have the role added into your database?  Here is some code I used in my seed method that essentially does what you want, minus using the views to do it:

```
        // Add the Admin role to the database
        IdentityResult roleResult;
        bool adminRoleExists = await _roleManager.RoleExistsAsync("Admin");
        if (!adminRoleExists)
        {
            _logger.LogInformation("Adding Admin role");
            roleResult = await _roleManager.CreateAsync(new IdentityRole("Admin"));
        }

        // Select the user, and then add the admin role to the user
        ApplicationUser user = await _userManager.FindByNameAsync("sysadmin");
        if (!await _userManager.IsInRoleAsync(user, "Admin"))
        {
            _logger.LogInformation("Adding sysadmin to Admin role");
            var userResult = await _userManager.AddToRoleAsync(user, "Admin");
        }
```

**EDIT**

The way you're adding roles right now leaves the NormalizedName field in the Role table null, which I believe is used by the framework for adding roles to users.  Try one of the following to add a role to the database instead of what you're currently doing:

```
var result = await _roleManager.CreateAsync(new IdentityRole(rolename));
```

Or this may also work (haven't tested this one though):

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Create(string rolename)
{
        _db.Roles.Add(new IdentityRole()
        {
            Name = rolename,
            NormalizedName = rolename.ToUpper()
        });
        _db.SaveChanges();
        ViewBag.ResultMessage = "Role created successfully!";
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

Comment: Thanks for catching that! The error says "Role [role] does not exist". I've edited my question. I have already added the role to my database (the drop-down list is populated with data from the "roles" table). Does the code you included in your answer work for you?

Comment: Yeah this is actual code I use to seed a new/empty database, but the basics should be the same. Could you post the code that's populating your select list? And how are you adding the role to the database to begin with?

Comment: that's interesting. I've added the code in the edit above. I'm adding the role to the database in a `Create` action in the controller with the `Add` method for the database.

Comment: This is bizarre.  I copy/pasted your code and it works just fine on my end.  I know that doesn't help you, but I'm wondering what else it could be now.  Are you on the latest .Net Core version?  How does the Identity portion of your startup.cs look?  I'm digging here, but would like to replicate the issue

Comment: I am on the latest .net core version (using the dependency `"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore": "1.0.0"` in _project.json_. I've added my `ConfigureServices` method in the edit above. I appreciate your suggestions!

Comment: I know I keep asking for more code, but could you show the code you're using to add the role to the database?  I was finally able to replicate your issue when I added the role manually with the DbContext instead of using the RoleManager

Comment: Sure! I've added the route above.

Comment: That's the same way I did it which caused it to fail!  Use RoleManager to create the role instead.  Replace your code with  the code I have in my answer (or something similar).  The following should work at a minimum: var result = await _roleManager.CreateAsync(new IdentityRole(rolename));  I believe that this is caused because the way you're adding it leaves the NormalizedName field in the Roles table null.  Alternatively, you could add the parameter NormalizedName = rolename.ToUpper() and that may also fix it.

Comment: I had the same issue with the NormalizedName column.  To update existing columns, I just ran an update sql `UPDATE [Roles] SET NormalizedName = UPPER(Name)`

Comment: Adding it straight to the database is a bad idea and violates every concept of encapsulation. See my answer for an alternative.

Comment: Is there any way to use RoleManager in conjuction with the modelBuilder HasData methods for data seeding?

Comment: Where did _roleManager come from??

Comment: @AndrewTorr in my case it’s being injected in the constructor. That part isn’t being shown in the example.

Comment: For me the problem was, that I originally had a role 'Super Admin' with normalized name 'SUPER ADMIN'. But then I manually changes the role name in database to 'SuperAdmin' (I removed space). That caused the error. I had to remove space in normalized column too

Answer (score 10):

Make sure when you are creating an AspNetRole the **`NormalizedName` should not be null** in order for the `UserManager` to work properly.

*NormalizedName should be upper-case using `.ToUpper()`*

Comment: this was the comment answer that put it all together!

Answer (score 2):

Adding it straight to the database is a bad idea and violates every concept of encapsulation, and NormalizedName is not something you should be computing yourself.

[See this answer](https://github.com/aspnet/Identity/issues/716#issuecomment-339148013)

Replace this code:

```
var roleStore = new RoleStore<IdentityRole>(context);
await roleStore.CreateAsync(new IdentityRole(role));
```

with following:

```
var roleManager = services.GetService<RoleManager<IdentityRole>>();
await roleManager.CreateAsync(new IdentityRole(role));
```

Comment: I agree that this is the better way to handle the case.  I gave this as an example also, and actually suggested it in the comments.  I however did not emphasize that going straight to the database is a bad practice, so thank you for that.

Answer (score 1):

This is the thing: if you are using major versions of identity (for example 6.0), the table AspNetRoles contains a Column named NormalizedName, if the string is null or differes from the role name written in capital letters you wont't be able to find the role name. You may insert manually (MMSMI) the string or delete per procedure all roles and recreate them.